# Write over a pdf file (template) with a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, itext

so i just heard about the API called iText and i'm not really familiar with its use.

So my problem now is i want to write over an existing pdf file (a template) the informations provided in a jsp form.
I tried some code found on the internet it works fine but not on servlets.
Thanks.

*EDIT* Here is the code i found and tried to put into a servlet.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            try {

                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(
                        "test.pdf")));
                document.open();
                String content = request.getParameter("aa");
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(content);
                document.add(paragraph);

            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                document.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Comment: _I tried some code found on the internet_ - tell us where you found that code, so that we can try it too.

Comment: i updated my post accordingly.

Comment: what do u mean it's not working on servlets? any exceptions, did you add the lib jar into the classpath? it's possible that the PDF file is actually created but somewhere else (not where you expect it) where do u think `new File("test.pdf")` will be created, if called from a servlet?

Comment: Oh yea my bad i forgot to mention that i get "HTTP 500 - The document has no pages." even tho the file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look at your servlet and I see:

```
new FileOutputStream(new File("test.pdf"))
```

This means that you are writing a file to the file system on your server. I don't see you sending any bytes to the `response` object, so nothing shows up in the browser.

You claim that iText "doesn't work in a servlet", but that's not correct: if no exception is thrown, a file named "test.pdf" is creating in your working directory on the server side. That's not very smart, because the more people use your servlet, the more PDFs will be saved on the server. You probably don't want that. You probably want to create the PDF in memory, and serve the PDF bytes to the browser.

The short answer to your question, is that you should write the PDF to the `OutputStream` of the `response` object instead of to a `FileOutputStream`:

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        try {
            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
            // step 3
            document.open();
            // step 4
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
            // step 5
            document.close();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new IOException(de.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

However, to avoid known issues with this approach, you should also read the official documentation. Search for the keyword "servlet" and you'll find these FAQ entries:

- [How can I serve a PDF to a browser without storing a file on the server side?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-serve-pdf-browser-without-storing-file-server-side) (iText 5)
- [How can I serve a PDF to a browser without storing a file on the server side?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/general-questions-about-itext/itext7-how-can-i-serve-pdf-browser-without-storing-file-server-side) (iText 7)

Since you are new at iText, it is surprising that you chose to use iText 5 instead of the newer iText 7. iText 7 isn't compatible with iText 5; it is a complete rewrite of the library. I recommend that you use iText 7, because we have stopped active development on iText 5.

**Update:**

The error known as "The document has no pages." indicates that you are trying to create a document that doesn't have any content.

Replace:

```
String content = request.getParameter("aa");
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(content);
document.add(paragraph);
```

With:

```
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello"));
```

My guess is that something went wrong while fetch the parameter `"aa"`, causing no content to be added to the document.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your extensive response :D 
I tried what you mentionned and it works, 
Thanks alot for that.